# How to select first item of a ListView by default that is populated by a Loader?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView that has images in it and these images come from server, a loader downloads the images then in `onLoadFinished` it `setAdapter` of ListView. After setting adapter, I try to select first item of ListView, but it has no effect. I suspected that ListView is not ready to select yet so I managed to do that by a strange way like overriding setSelection function:

```
public void setSelection(final int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "thread runned.");
            boolean is_view_created = false;

            while (!is_view_created) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    getListView();
                    if (getListView().getChildAt(position) != null)
                        is_view_created = true;
                    else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Waiting for the list view to initialize.");
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Waiting for the list view to initialize.");
                }
            }
            MiddleMenuListFragment.super.setSelection(position);
            View initial_selection_view = getListView().getChildAt(position);
            initial_selection_view.performClick();
            ((MiddleMenuListAdapter)getListAdapter()).light_me_up = position;
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ((MiddleMenuListAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();   
                }
            });

        }
    }, 400);
}
```

But this method is not really safe. It sometimes enters the loop (can't get `getListView().getChildAt(position != null)` true). Can you advise more elegant solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't using header you can listen `ListView` hierarchy change with `OnHierarchyChangeListener`

```
private boolean needSelection = true;

public void onChildViewAdded(View parent, View child) {
  if (needSelection && indexOfChild(child) == 0) {
    trySelectChild(child);
    needSelection = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just [register](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#registerDataSetObserver%28android.database.DataSetObserver%29) a [DataSetObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DataSetObserver.html) against the ListAdapter to set the selection on the [onChange()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DataSetObserver.html#onChanged%28%29) event once there is 1 or more items in the ListAdapter?

Comment: Nope, it has an unpredictable effect again. (sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't (I think because of network conditions causes the loading time)